# Why does my code loop through twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to figure out why my code is looping twice, I'm thinking it's because I'm checking two different classes ('.wrapper, .surround') but I can't think of another way to write that. Is this the reason my code is looping twice? I wan to check the vars backAwayVal and backAwayHome if the bet-button is clicked on the surround div. and I want to check the awayVal and homeVal if the bet-button is clicked on the wrapper div. However if I click on the wrapper div bet-button it console.logs twice.

```
$('.wrapper, .surround').on('click', '.bet-button', function(){
    var self = $(this);
    console.log(self);

    var gameId = self.attr('gameid');

    var awayVal = $('#' + gameId + ' input[name=betAmountAway]').val();
    var homeVal = $('#' + gameId + ' input[name=betAmountHome]').val();

    var backAwayVal = $('#' + gameId + ' input[name=back-away-val]').val();
    var backHomeVal = $('#' + gameId + ' input[name=back-home-val]').val();

    var awayId = $('#' + gameId + ' .bet-input-away').data('away-id');
    var homeId = $('#' + gameId + ' .bet-input-home').data('home-id');

    var pointTotals = $('#' + gameId + ' .total-points').val();

    var id, value;

    if (awayVal) {
      id = awayId;
      value = awayVal;
    }
    if (homeVal) {
      id = awayId;
      value = homeVal;
    }
    if (backAwayVal) {
      id = awayId;
      value = backAwayVal;
    }
    if (backHomeVal) {
      id = homeId;
      value = backHomeVal;
    }if (!value) {
        alert('please enter a value!')
    }else {}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="surround">
  <div class="wrapper col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-12"></div>
  <div class="signup-popup-background">
    <div class="signup-popup">
      <div class="close-button"><i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i></div>
      <div class="sign-in-register">
        <div class="register">
          <div id="register-box">
            <a class="fill-div" href="{{ www }}user/register/"><p>Register</p></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="signup">
          <div id="sign-in-box">
            <a class="fill-div" href="{{ www }}user/login/"><p>Sign In</p></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="betting-popup">
    <div class="checkmark">
        <i class="fas fa-check-circle check"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="bet-info">
        <span class="betting-popup-name"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="bet-amount">
        <span class="betting-popup-amount"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
<div class="twitter-background">
  <div class="twitter-popup">
    <div class="twitter-submit-button">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: indeed, if .surround is inside .wrapper, or vice versa, then you may get this happening twice (it's not **looping** as such) ... surely `console.log(self);` logs two different elements?

Comment: @MiguelAngel So I have two HTML docs, one is generated within the javascript, and the other is generated in actual html

Comment: @JaromandaX so one HTML is being generated dynamically through the javascript, and one is being generated through html.

Comment: how the HTML is generated is irrelevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next time share the html too, this looks like a bubbling problem, 
you can

```
$('.wrapper, .surround').on('click', '.bet-button', function(e){ 
e.stopPropagation();
// do your logic
}
```

hope this works.

Comment: I added the html

Comment: Ok so I think that works, can you explain why that works?

Comment: It works because the if you click on the `.bet-button` in the `surround`, that only triggers once. But you have `wrapper` inside surround, so it's bubbling for both `.wrapper .bet-button` and `.surround .bet-button` - since both handlers were triggered. You could solve this by moving the event handler up the DOM, for example's sake: `$(document).on('click', '.surround .bet-button, .wrapper .bet-button', function(){`

Comment: Best to read [event.stopPropagation() in the jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

Comment: yes, the '$('.wrapper, .surround')' is returning 2 elements, one for the `surround` and another one for the `wrapper`, then you're binding an event to both, then when you click it, both events been called, because is the the parent and the child are click events, `e.stopPropagation()` is not the best option here because you're stopping all the execution not just the double loop, the best for you will be improve the query selector to be more specific and just bind once the event. all depends of what exactly you want.

Answer (score 1):

Using `e.stopPropagation();` should work, but I want to clarify what's happening.

You have a `.bet-button` inside just the `.surround`, and another inside the `.wrapper`.

However, `.wrapper` is *inside* `.surround` so the handler bubbles through both:

```
<surround>
    <bet-button 1>
    <wrapper>
        <bet-button 2>
    </wrapper>
</surround>
```

With your current code, if you click on the <kbd>bet-button 1</kbd> it works as you expect. However if you click on <kbd>bet-button 2</kbd>, the event will return two elements, because it's meeting **both** `.wrapper .bet-button` and `.surround .bet-button`.

To get around this you can move the handler up the DOM to `surrounds` parent, or just to the `document`, and then modify your selector like so:

```
$(document).on('click', '.surround .bet-button, .wrapper .bet-button', function(){
```